# WebKit Animation Started, but Frozen on First Frame (Safari Only)

Tags: javascript, css, safari, webkit, css-transitions

**Works on All Modern Browsers, Except Safari**

Here's a very rare situation and possible glitch with *Safari*. I'm dynamically adding the **.highlighted** class to the **fieldset** element with JS.

Here's the unusual part... it starts out stuck on the first frame until I trigger a separate animation on a different element (ex: button hover webkit anim). I've tried to invoke the play state through CSS directly and JS. I've spent the whole day bashing my head against the wall.

I've also tried using transition attributes on the base style as well, but no luck.

**The CSS**

```
footer form fieldset {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background:#000;
    width:80%;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;        
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #888;
  }
  footer form fieldset.highlighted {
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.7s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running !important;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0% { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #888; }
    50% { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888; }
    100% { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #888; }
  }
```

I also tried using JS, binding "webkitAnimationEnd" event to the fieldset, then setting the play state (Example):

```
document.getElementById('blah').style.webkitAnimationPlayState='running';
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out last minute finally! Conflicting CSS3 transition styles applied. Once removed, works now.

**Lesson learned, be careful with mixing CSS3 transitions with WebKit keyframed animations.**

```
.transition-med
{
   transition:all 0.5s ease;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, instead of using the "all" property in transitions, use something more specific like "opacity" or "width".

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property-property